# Install Git on OSX 10.8

Tags: git, openssl

ALL,

My project is located on GitHub which recently switched to using TLS1.2, which is incompatible with the OpenSSL version OSX 10.8 ships with.

So I tried to build Git from sources.

I downloaded the archive, unpack it and created config.mak file where I put following:

```
NO_GETTEXT=Yes
NO_OPENSSL=Yes
```

The build finished successfully, but when I tried to run it I still received:

```
MyMac:dbhandler igorkorot$ /Users/igorkorot/git-2.17.0/git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/oneeyeman1/dbhandler.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Is there an easy way to check what version of OpenSSL will be linked if I remove the line `NO_OPENSSL=YES` from the config.mak file? I will try to remove that line and do `make clean && make` after that. I did update whatever the notification was suggesting, but don't know if OpenSSL was part of the update.

I just need the latest version of the library. Hopefully there is still one available for OSX 10.8.

The machine is old and I don't want to install anything extra (homebrew or such) unless absolutely necessary.

TIA!

Comment: Why nt upgrade macOS?

Answer (score 1):

I had Homebrew installed already, so these four steps were enough:

1. `brew install openssl`
2. `brew install git`
3. `mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git.old`
4. Add `[http]` `sslVersion = tlsv1.2` to `$HOME/.gitconfig`

Note that you need to install new openssl before building new git, otherwise it will link against the old system version of openssl.

Comment: As long as `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in `PATH` you shouldn't need to rename the old one (which AFAIK requires you to disable SIP anyway).

Comment: @nohillside True for recent versions of Mac OS X; but SIP doesn't exist on OS X 10.8. Not sure about the PATH, whether homebrew somehow had different default configuration on old versions, I think the PATH order is correct on later ones automatically also.

Comment: Ah, 10.8, didn't notice this before.

Comment: @nohillside Heh :) I guess I'm not the only one running ancient build servers and not wanting to touch them more than necessary.